# How to set the html date in Angular 8 from TypeScript Code

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular 8.
Any hint or help would be greatly appreciated it!!
I have the following

```
<input id="startDate" name="startDate" type="date"  [(ngModel)]="startDate" required #startDate2="ngModel" />
```

I have the following typescript code which get the current date minus 3 months from now.

```
let threeMonthsFromCurrentDate = new Date();
threeMonthsFromCurrentDate.setMonth(threeMonthsFromCurrentDate.getMonth() - 3);


this.startDate = threeMonthsFromCurrentDate;
this.startDate = new Date( threeMonthsFromCurrentDate.getFullYear(),threeMonthsFromCurrentDate.getMonth(),threeMonthsFromCurrentDate.getDate());
```

In the browser, the startDate doesn't show 3 months ago :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should use Date Pipe to format the date because `input type=date` is accepting only one format so

You can change your **HTML** to :

```
<input id="startDate" name="startDate" type="date"  [ngModel]="startDate | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'" required #startDate2="ngModel" />
```

**Or** you can change your **TS** to:

```
 this.startDate = threeMonthsFromCurrentDate.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a method that return formatted date by using Date Pipe

```
convertDateToDisplay = (date) => {
    return this.datepipe.transform(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
}
```

**form.html**

```
<input required type="date"
            class="form-control" formControlName="StartDt"
            />
```

**form.component.ts**

```
_form: FormGroup;
                
ngOnInit(): void {
this._form= this.fb.group({
StartDt:''
});
                   
this.getData();
}
            
// Get Data from Database
public getData(){
 this.Service.getByData().subscribe((x) => {          
   this._form.controls['StartDt'].patchValue(this.convertDateToDisplay(x.StartDt));
});
}
        
public convertDateToDisplay = (date) => {
 return this.datepipe.transform(date, 'yyyy-MM-dd')
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can check it here. It is actually exactly same use of DatePipe in html.
https://angular.io/api/common/formatDate

```
import { formatDate } from '@angular/common';
```

For example:

```
this.startDate = formatDate(yourDateValue, 'M/d/yy, h:mm a', 'en-US', '+0430');
```